# Cascading Dropdown, but in any selection order

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to do cascading dropdown boxes for 4 fields, but instead of selecting in a set order (i.e. Country, State, City, Zip), I would like to be able to select in any possible order (i.e. pick City first, and all other dropdown's options update). Can someone please point me in the right direction on finding potential resources/options for this? Also is there a term for this, since I'm assuming it would no longer be cascading with this change?

In the example below I have 2 states with the city Portland. Currently, I can select the Country (USA), then either the state of Maine or Oregon to and Portland will be one of the options for City. I would like it so at page load, all potential options for each select box are loaded, so I could choose to pick city - Portland first and Country, State, and Zip options will update to reflect the filtered options.

**4 Dropdowns - country, state, city, zip**

```
<select id="country" onchange="updateState()">
  <option value="">Select Country</option>
  <option value="USA">USA</option>
  <option value="India">India</option>
</select>

<label for="state">State:</label>
<select id="state" onchange="updateCity()">
  <option value="">Select State</option>
</select>

<label for="city">City:</label>
<select id="city" onchange="updateZip()">
  <option value="">Select City</option>
</select>

<label for="zip">Zip:</label>
<select id="zip">
  <option value="">Select Zip</option>
</select>
```

**var countryStateInfo. In this example you can see there are 2 cities of Portland  - 1 in Maine, 1 in Oregon.**

```
var countryStateInfo = {
    "USA": {
        "California": {
            "Los Angeles": ["90001", "90002", "90003", "90004"],
            "San Diego": ["92093", "92101"]
        },
    "Maine": {
            "Portland": ["04101"],
            "Augusta": ["04330"]
        },
    "Oregon": {
            "Portland": ["97035","97203"],
            "Eugene": ["97404"]
        }
    },
    "India": {
        "Assam": {
            "Dispur": ["781005"],
            "Guwahati" : ["781030", "781030"]
        },
        "Gujarat": {
            "Vadodara" : ["390011", "390020"],
            "Surat" : ["395006", "395002"]
        }
    }
}
```

**Current JavaScript code which is handling cascading filtering (only in 1 direction)**

```
  const countrySelect = document.getElementById("country");
  const stateSelect = document.getElementById("state");
  const citySelect = document.getElementById("city");
  const zipSelect = document.getElementById("zip");

  // Update the state
  function updateState() {
    stateSelect.innerHTML = "<option value=''>Select State</option>";
    citySelect.innerHTML = "<option value=''>Select City</option>";
    zipSelect.innerHTML = "<option value=''>Select Zip</option>";

    const selectedCountry = countrySelect.value;
    if (selectedCountry !== "") {
      const states = countryStateInfo[selectedCountry];
      for (const state in states) {
        const option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = state;
        option.textContent = state;
        stateSelect.appendChild(option);
      }
    }
  }

  // Update the city
  function updateCity() {
    citySelect.innerHTML = "<option value=''>Select City</option>";
    zipSelect.innerHTML = "<option value=''>Select Zip</option>";

    const selectedCountry = countrySelect.value;
    const selectedState = stateSelect.value;
    if (selectedCountry !== "" && selectedState !== "") {
      const cities = countryStateInfo[selectedCountry][selectedState];
      for (const city in cities) {
        const option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = city;
        option.textContent = city;
        citySelect.appendChild(option);
      }
    }
  }

  // Update the zip
  function updateZip() {
    zipSelect.innerHTML = "<option value=''>Select Zip</option>";

    const selectedCountry = countrySelect.value;
    const selectedState = stateSelect.value;
    const selectedCity = citySelect.value;
    if (
      selectedCountry !== "" &&
      selectedState !== "" &&
      selectedCity !== ""
    ) {
      const zips = countryStateInfo[selectedCountry][selectedState][selectedCity];
      for (const zip of zips) {
        const option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = zip;
        option.textContent = zip;
        zipSelect.appendChild(option);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I have been playing around with the code and poking it with error catching tools and realized there's an issue with the declaration of the variables containing references to the `select` elements. I will hopefully get this figured out soon.

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed the code. The JavaScript code doesn't wait until the elements load before grabbing the elements by ID, therefore they contain `null`. To fix this, define the variables as empty with `var countrySelect;` for example, then use `window.onload = function(){ [give them values] };` to force JavaScript to wait before grabbing.

```js
var countryStateInfo = {
    "USA": {
        "California": {
            "Los Angeles": ["90001", "90002", "90003", "90004"],
            "San Diego": ["92093", "92101"]
        },
    "Maine": {
            "Portland": ["04101"],
            "Augusta": ["04330"]
        },
    "Oregon": {
            "Portland": ["97035","97203"],
            "Eugene": ["97404"]
        }
    },
    "India": {
        "Assam": {
            "Dispur": ["781005"],
            "Guwahati" : ["781030", "781030"]
        },
        "Gujarat": {
            "Vadodara" : ["390011", "390020"],
            "Surat" : ["395006", "395002"]
        }
    }
};
var countrySelect;
var stateSelect;
var citySelect;
var zipSelect;
setTimeout(() => {
  countrySelect = document.getElementById("country");
  stateSelect = document.getElementById("state");
  citySelect = document.getElementById("city");
  zipSelect = document.getElementById("zip");
  initialValues();
},100);

function initialValues(){
  for(var country in countryStateInfo){
    for(var state in countryStateInfo[country]){
      const option = document.createElement("option");
      option.value = state;
      option.textContent = state;
      stateSelect.appendChild(option);
      for(var city in countryStateInfo[country][state]){
        const option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = city;
        option.textContent = city;
        citySelect.appendChild(option);
        for(var i = 0; i < countryStateInfo[country][state][city].length; i++){
          var zip = countryStateInfo[country][state][city][i];
          const option = document.createElement("option");
          option.value = zip;
          option.textContent = zip;
          zipSelect.appendChild(option);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

  // Update the state
  function updateState() {
    stateSelect.innerHTML = "<option value=''>Select State</option>";
    citySelect.innerHTML = "<option value=''>Select City</option>";
    zipSelect.innerHTML = "<option value=''>Select Zip</option>";

    const selectedCountry = countrySelect.value;
    if (selectedCountry !== "") {
      const states = countryStateInfo[selectedCountry];
      for (const state in states) {
        const option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = state;
        option.textContent = state;
        stateSelect.appendChild(option);
      }
    }
  }

  // Update the city
  function updateCity() {
    citySelect.innerHTML = "<option value=''>Select City</option>";
    zipSelect.innerHTML = "<option value=''>Select Zip</option>";

    const selectedCountry = countrySelect.value;
    const selectedState = stateSelect.value;
    if (selectedCountry !== "" && selectedState !== "") {
      const cities = countryStateInfo[selectedCountry][selectedState];
      for (const city in cities) {
        const option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = city;
        option.textContent = city;
        citySelect.appendChild(option);
      }
    }
    var e = "";
    for(var country in countryStateInfo){
      if(Object.keys(countryStateInfo[country]).indexOf(selectedState) != -1){
        e = country;
      }
    }
    if(selectedCountry != e){
      countrySelect.value = e;
    }
  }

  // Update the zip
  function updateZip() {
    zipSelect.innerHTML = "<option value=''>Select Zip</option>";

    const selectedCountry = countrySelect.value;
    const selectedState = stateSelect.value;
    const selectedCity = citySelect.value;
    if (
      selectedCountry !== "" &&
      selectedState !== "" &&
      selectedCity !== ""
    ) {
      const zips = countryStateInfo[selectedCountry][selectedState][selectedCity];
      for (const zip of zips) {
        const option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = zip;
        option.textContent = zip;
        zipSelect.appendChild(option);
      }
    }
  }
```

```html
<select id="country" onchange="updateState()">
  <option value="">Select Country</option>
  <option value="USA">USA</option>
  <option value="India">India</option>
</select>

<label for="state">State:</label>
<select id="state" onchange="updateCity()">
  <option value="">Select State</option>
</select>

<label for="city">City:</label>
<select id="city" onchange="updateZip()">
  <option value="">Select City</option>
</select>

<label for="zip">Zip:</label>
<select id="zip">
  <option value="">Select Zip</option>
</select>
```

Don't worry, many programmers suffer from this every day. There is help online that you can use to identify these issues, if you could look using error identification.

```
window.onerror = function(e){
    alert(e);
};
// This can tell you when an error occurs, and what the error is.
```

Comment: Sorry if my question was not totally clear. The example I gave only allows for filtering one way Country -> State -> City -> Zip. I am trying to find a way where The order of selection does not matter. So when the page initially loads, all four dropdowns will have all options available. Then a user can select from any of the 4 select boxes first. So, a user could decide to select a Country from the list first (and all the other selects' options would update) or they could decide to select a City first and all the other selects' option values would update.

Comment: I have added a function called `initialValues()` which does what you asked.

Comment: Great this seems allow all options to load during page load. Do you have any thought on updating the other selects' option values when a selection is made? i.e. in the example, if a user decides to select city 'Portland' first, the options for Country would update to "USA" only, the options for state would update to "Maine" & "Oregon", and the options for zip would be "04101" & "97035" & "97203". This would be similar to filtering in Excel, where you can select a filter in any column and all of the filters in all other columns would update to only the option values available.

Comment: I have added a little bit of code to `updateCity()` that makes it change the Country select. I would probably need help with implementing it within the code for the other functions. I was going to do so, but I rethought the whole thing and realized it would take a lot of effort to do the other functions.

Comment: Ah okay I see what you did. I think I have an understanding of how this can be implemented. I will try an piggyback off your response and post if I can complete it this way. Thanks